# How to link a pdf download in JsonStore for Extjs 3.4

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I would like to have the pdf item (f_release_note) be a link to open the pdf.
f_release_note - is stored in the database as blob.

```
Medit.Admin.ReleaseNotes.Stores.ReleaseNotes = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    storeId: 'ReleaseNotes',
    url: 'fc.php?_C_A=ReleaseNotes.getList',
    root: 'root',
    remoteSort: true,
    autoLoad: true,
    successProperty: 'succcess',
    baseParams: {
        start: 0,
        limit: 25
    },
    idProperty: 'f_uid',
    fields: [{
        name: 'f_uid',
        type: 'int'
    
    }, {
        name: 'f_release',
        type: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'm/d/Y'
    
    },{
        name:'f_version_number',
        type: 'string'
    },{
       name:'f_release_note',
       type:'string'
    }]
});
```

Screen display
Release Notes

Release     Version Number      Release Note
2/09/2021   25.01.01            Release 21.01 pdf

I would like to have the ability for the user to click Release 21.01 pdf and open the pdf file.

Comment: May you provide a little bit more information?

Comment: Medit.Admin.ReleaseNotes.Views.GridPanel = Ext.extend(Medit.grid.GridPanel,{   
     gridColumns = [this.sm,{
                id: 'f_release',
                dataIndex: 'f_release',   xtype: 'datecolumn', format: 'm/d/Y', header 'Release',  width: 35
            }, {
                id: 'f_version_number', header: 'Version Number',  dataIndex:'f_version_number',     width: 45
            }, {
                id:'f_release_note' ,  header: 'Release Note ',  dataIndex: 'f_release_note',
                width: 45
            }];
        }

Comment: You need to define appropriate renderer in the grid column model to create a HTML link.

Comment: In the renderer do I need to store the data (columnIndex) in a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
items: [{
  layout: 'fit',
  html: '<iframe src="resources/docs/releaseinfo/' + record.get('filenameOrSomething') + '.pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;"/>'
}],
```

Or just an regular link to a blank window?